# R Alternative testing

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I am currently a student using R for testing alternate hypothesis. I was given a set of data with multiple stocks, returns, s&p 500 returns and more. I am trying to figure out how to write the code to test alternate hypothesis that the stock’s mean return is higher than that of the S&P 500 index. Every code I run give me a error. any advice on how to handle this would be great.

Comment: Hi @Mathis, Welcome to SO!  Can you include the code you are trying and the input data as well? That will helps others try to assist you with your question.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg